# Find a linear function for this complex mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Find a linear function $f(z)=az+b$ that maps the circle $|z-1| = 1$ to onto the circle $|z-1|=3$ and at the same time 2 maps to $3i+1$. In this problem i geometrically sketch it out and i know that a linear function does three things dilation, rotation, and translation. but the real question i am basically asking is how do write a linear function for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Affine functions preserve ratios of distances. So the center of the circle will be a fixed point. That is, $f(1) = 1 = a + b$. You also know that $f(2) = 3i + 1 = 2a + b$. So you are led to the pair of equations
$$ \begin{cases}
a + b = 1 \\
2a + b = 3i + 1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: the second equation should be $2a+b = 3i+1$ right

Comment: @user146269 Yep, it should be!